# Can you use a chain for an old sharp chainsaw on an echo chainsaw?

Tags: chainsaw

Can you use a chain for a sharp chainsaw on a echo chainsaw?

Comment: If it's not listed as a compatible  blade, don't use it.  It's not worth the risk if it slips off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I don’t see this as a shopping question but a question that is lacking the type of chain. If both saws are the same length bar it may be possible, if the same length then the drive dogs would have be the same size and profile. FYI , some saws have safety’s so if the saw kicks back it locks the chain, using a aggressive chain without a anti kickback safety you could loose a body part, one of the guys that worked for my dad lost 2 fingers cutting wood on a weekend from kickback, so there are several things to consider other than length , dog profile. And tooth cut.

Comment: if you have to ask, then you should not be doing it .... are you going to risk your safety on the word of a stranger on the internet?

Comment: As far as I know, chainsaw blades are not a standard item that can be switched out between manufacturers without issue... and this seems like a particularly dangerous thing to "try it and see" with.

Comment: All the saws I've used had similar looking blade mounts, but to be safe I'd talk to a chainsaw expert like an arbourist or a outdoor power equipment seller.

If there are details to the blades that makes them incompatible they should know.

  You could check the manual too, but the manual is not only for your protection, it is often also advertising.

Comment: @jsotola everyone starts somewhere. At least the OP thought to ask, apparently to educate themselves, and didn't just blunder into an accident.